# Sending HTML mail via ASP Form

Tags: html, email, asp-classic

I have an ASP Form. I wish to send the completed form details, in HTML, with proper formatting (table).

The old way I was doing was writing an entire script into a variable, then sending the message that way.

```
message = "<html><body>"
message = message + " "&_ 'Many lines of codes!
message = message + "</body></html>"
```

As my form can get very long, do you all have a better recommendation on how I can send an entire HTML page, without putting it within a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Create template.html and layout the page any way you like. If you are broadcasting to multiple recipients, you can put the text like this "Hi [varFirstName]" in your template.

Then you can import that template file in the code as follow.

```
    Dim fso,templatesource,body
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set templatesource = fso.OpenTextFile(server.MapPath("template.html")) 
    template=templatesource.ReadAll
    template= Replace(template,"[varFirstName]",rsSource("firstname"))
    file.close
    templatesource.close
    Set templatesource = nothing
    Set fso = nothing
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the TextStream after `ReadAll` also use `Server.HTMLEncode` on text being injected into the HTML.

Comment: @Jonas T does your example ammend the html template directly, or it copies it?